# Concatenate several seq within a file according to their percentage of similarities

Tags: python, concatenation, string-concatenation

Hel lo I need your help in a complicated task.

Here is a `file1.txt` :

```
>Name1.1_1-40_-__Sp1
AAAAAACC-------------
>Name1.1_67-90_-__Sp1
------CCCCCCCCC------
>Name1.1_90-32_-__Sp1
--------------CCDDDDD
>Name2.1_20-89_-__Sp2
AAAAAACCCCCCCCCCC----
>Name2.1_78-200_-__Sp2
-------CCCCCCCCCCDDDD
```

and the idea is to create a new file called `file1.txt_Hsp` such as:

```
>Name1.1-3HSPs-__Sp1
AAAAAACCCCCCCCCCDDDDD
>Name3.1_-__Sp2
AAAAAACCCCCCCCCCC----
>Name4.1_-__Sp2
-------CCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

So basically the idea is to:

- Compare each sequence `from the same SpN` <-- (here it is very important only with the same SpN name) with each other in `file1.txt`. 
  For instance I will have to compare :
- `Name1.1_1-40_-__Sp1 vs Name1.1_67-90_-__Sp1`
- `Name1.1_1-40_-__Sp1 vs Name1.1_90-32_-__Sp1`
- `Name1.1_67-90_-__Sp1 vs Name1.1_90-32_-__Sp1`
- `Name2.1_20-89_-__Sp2 vs Name2.1_78-200_-__Sp2`

So for exemple when I compare:

`Name1.1_1-40_-__Sp1 vs Name1.1_67-90_-__Sp1` I get :

```
>Name1.1_1-40_-__Sp1
AAAAAACC-------------
>Name1.1_67-90_-__Sp1
------CCCCCCCCC------
```

here I want to concatenate the two sequences if `ratio between number of letter matching with another letter / nb letter matching with a (-)` is < 0.20`.

Here for example there are `21 characters`, and the number of letter matching with another letter = 2 (`C and C`).
And the number of letter that match with a `-` , is `13` (`AAAAAA+CCCCCCC`)

so

```
ratio = 2/15 : 0.1538462
```

and if this `ratio < 0.20`  then I want to **concatenate** this 2 sequences such as :

```
>Name1.1-2HSPs_-__Sp1
AAAAAACCCCCCCCC------
```

(As you can se the name of the new seq is now : Name.1-2HSPs_-__Sp1 with the 2 meaning that there are 2 sequences concatenated) So we remove the number-number part for XHSPS with X being the number of sequence concatenated. 
and get the file1.txt_Hsp :

```
>Name1.1-2HSPs_-__Sp1
AAAAAACCCCCCCCC------
>Name1.1_90-32_-__Sp1
--------------CCDDDDD
>Name2.1_20-89_-__Sp2
AAAAAACCCCCCCCCCC----
>Name2.1_78-200_-__Sp2
-------CCCCCCCCCCDDDD
```

Then I do it again with `Name1.1-2HSPs_-__Sp1 vs Name1.1_90-32_-__Sp1`

```
>Name1.1-2HSPs_-__Sp1
AAAAAACCCCCCCCC------
>Name1.1_90-32-__Sp1
--------------CCDDDDD

Where ratio = 1/20 = 0.05
```

Then  because the `ratio is < 0.20` I want to **concatenate** this 2 sequences such as :

```
>Name1.1-3HSPs_-__Sp1
AAAAAACCCCCCCCCCDDDDD
```

(As you can see the name of the new seq is now : Name.1-3HSPs_-__Sp1 with the 3 meaning that there are 3 sequences concatenated)

```
file1.txt_Hsp:

>Name1.1-3HSPs_-__Sp1
AAAAAACCCCCCCCCCDDDDD
>Name2.1_20-89_-__Sp2
AAAAAACCCCCCCCCCC----
>Name2.1_78-200_-__Sp2
-------CCCCCCCCCCDDDD
```

Then I do it again with `Name2.1_20-89_-__Sp2` vs `Name2.1_78-200_-__Sp2`

```
>Name2.1_20-89_-__Sp2
AAAAAACCCCCCCCCCC----
>Name2.1_78-200_-__Sp2
-------CCCCCCCCCCDDDD

Where ratio = 10/11 = 0.9090909
```

Then  because the `ratio is > 0.20` I do nothing and get the final `file1.txt_Hsp`:

```
>Name1.1-3HSPs_-__Sp1
AAAAAACCCCCCCCCCDDDDD
>Name2.1_20-89_-__Sp2
AAAAAACCCCCCCCCCC----
>Name2.1_78-200_-__Sp2
-------CCCCCCCCCCDDDD
```

Which is the final result I needed.

---

**A simplest exemple would be :**

```
>Name1.1_10-60_-__Seq1
AAA------
>Name1.1_70-120_-__Seq1
--AAAAAAA
>Name2.1_12-78_-__Seq2
--AAAAAAA
```

The ratio is `1/8 = 0.125` because only 1 letter is matching and 8 because 8 letters are matching with a (-)

Because the `ratio < 0.20` I concatenate the two sequences Seq1 to:

```
>Name1.1_2HSPs_-__Seq1
AAAAAAAAA
```

and the new file should be :

```
>Name1.1_2HSPs_-__Seq1
AAAAAAAAA
>Name2.1_-__Seq2
--AAAAAAA
```

** Here is an exemple from my real data **

```
>YP_009186705
MMSCQSWMMKYFTKVCNRSNLALPFDQSVNPVSFSMISSHDVMLKLDDEIFYKSLNQSNL
ALPFDQSVNPVSFSMISSHDLIA
>XO009980.1_26784332-20639090_-__Agapornis_vilveti
------------------------------------------------------LNQSNL
ALPFDQSVNPVSFSMISSHDLIA
>CM009917.1_20634332-20634508_-__Neodiprion_lecontei
---CDSWMIKFFARISQMC---IKIHSKYEEVSFFLFQSK--KKKIADSHFFRSLNQDTA
-------LNTVSY----------
>XO009980.1_20634508-20634890_-__Agapornis_vilveti
MMSCQSWMMKYFTKVCNRSNLALPFDQSVNPVSFSMISSHDVMLKL--------------
-----------------------
>YUUBBOX12
MMSCQSWMMKYFTKVCNRSNLALPFDQSVNPVSFSMISSHDVMLKLDDEIFYKSLNQSNL
ALPFDQSVNPVSFSMISSHDLIA
```

and I should get :

```
>YP_009186705
MMSCQSWMMKYFTKVCNRSNLALPFDQSVNPVSFSMISSHDVMLKLDDEIFYKSLNQSNL
ALPFDQSVNPVSFSMISSHDLIA
>XO009980.1_2HSPs_-__Agapornis_vilveti
MMSCQSWMMKYFTKVCNRSNLALPFDQSVNPVSFSMISSHDVMLKLLNQSNL
ALPFDQSVNPVSFSMISSHDLIA
>CM009917.1_20634332-20634508_-__Neodiprion_lecontei
---CDSWMIKFFARISQMC---IKIHSKYEEVSFFLFQSK--KKKIADSHFFRSLNQDTA
-------LNTVSY----------
>YUUBBOX12
MMSCQSWMMKYFTKVCNRSNLALPFDQSVNPVSFSMISSHDVMLKLDDEIFYKSLNQSNL
ALPFDQSVNPVSFSMISSHDLIA
```

the ratio between `XO009980.1_26784332-20639090_-__Agapornis_vilveti` and `XO009980.1_20634508-20634890_-__Agapornis_vilveti` was : 0/75 = 0

Here as you can see, some sequence does not have the `[\d]+[-]+[\d]` patterns such as `YP_009186705` or `YUUBBOX12`, these one does not have to be concatenate, they juste have to be added in the outputfile.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Shouldn't the name of the concatenated entry in your simple example be `Name.1_2HSPs_Seq1`? Why have you left out the `_Seq1` when you kept a part (`_Sp1`) from the entire suffix (`-__Sp1`) in the earlier instance? I am confused about how you're calculating the `Name` strings.

Comment: @darthbhyrava thank you for the remarks, I edited it. For the Name strings you mean the ratio or whether it is Name.1_2HSPs_-__Seq1 or Name.1_3HSPs_-__Seq1 ?

Comment: The latter - could you please expand on how the new is calculated after a concat occurs?

Comment: @darthbhyrava let me edit the example to explain it better.

Comment: @darthbhyrava I completly changed the name of the sequences. As you can see now the name of the new seq is : Name.1-2HSPs_-__Sp1 with the 2 meaning that there are 2 sequences concatenated) So we remove the number-number part for XHSPs with X being the number of sequence concatenated.

Comment: This helps a lot, thanks, I'll reply with an answer shortly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203380/discussion-between-darthbhyrava-and-chippycentra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's read the text files into tuples of `(name, seq)`:

```
with open('seq.txt', 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
seq_map = []
for i in range(0, len(lines), 2):
    seq_map.append((lines[i].strip('\n'), lines[i+1].strip('\n')))

#[('>Name1.1_10-60_-__Seq1', 'AAA------'),
# ('>Name1.1_70-120_-__Seq1', '--AAAAAAA'),
# ('>Name2.1_12-78_-__Seq2', '--AAAAAAA')]
#
# or
#
# [('>Name1.1_1-40_-__Sp1', 'AAAAAACC-------------'),
#  ('>Name1.1_67-90_-__Sp1', '------CCCCCCCCC------'),
#  ('>Name1.1_90-32_-__Sp1', '--------------CCDDDDD'),
#  ('>Name2.1_20-89_-__Sp2', 'AAAAAACCCCCCCCCCC----'),
#  ('>Name2.1_78-200_-__Sp2', '-------CCCCCCCCCCDDDD')]
```

Then we define helper functions, one each for checking for a concat, then concat for seq, and merge for name (with a nest helper for getting HSPs counts):

```
import re

def count_num(x):
    num = re.findall(r'[\d]+?(?=HSPs)', x)
    count = int(num[0]) if num and 'HSPs' in x else 1
    return count

def concat_name(nx, ny):
    count, new_name = 0, []
    count += count_num(nx)
    count += count_num(ny)
    for ind, x in enumerate(nx.split('_')):
        if ind == 1:
            new_name.append('{}HSPs'.format(count))
        else:
            new_name.append(x)
    new_name = '_'.join([x for x in new_name])
    return new_name

def concat_seq(x, y):
    mash, new_seq = zip(x, y), ''
    for i in mash:
        if i.count('-') > 1:
            new_seq += '-'
        else:
            new_seq += i[0] if i[1] == '-' else i[1]
    return new_seq

def check_concat(x, y):
    mash, sim, dissim = zip(x, y), 0 ,0
    for i in mash:
        if i[0] == i[1] and '-' not in i:
            sim += 1
        if '-' in i and i.count('-') == 1:
            dissim += 1
    return False if not dissim or float(sim)/float(dissim) >= 0.2 else True
```

Then we will write a script to run over the tuples in sequence, checking for spn matches, then concat_checks, and taking forward the new pairing for the next comparison, adding to the final list where necessary:

```
tmp_seq_map = seq_map[:]
final_seq = []

for ind in range(1, len(seq_map)):
    end = True if ind == len(seq_map)-1 else False
    pair_a = tmp_seq_map[ind-1]
    pair_b = tmp_seq_map[ind]

    name_a = pair_a[0][:]
    name_b = pair_b[0][:]

    if name_a.split('__')[1] == name_b.split('__')[1]:

        if check_concat(pair_a[1], pair_b[1]):

            new_name = concat_name(pair_a[0], pair_b[0])
            new_seq = concat_seq(pair_a[1], pair_b[1])
            tmp_seq_map[ind] = (((new_name, new_seq)))

            if end:
                final_seq.append(tmp_seq_map[ind])
                end = False
        else:
            final_seq.append(pair_a)
    else:
        final_seq.append(pair_a)
    if end:
        final_seq.append(pair_b)
print(final_seq)

#[('>Name1.1_2HSPs_-__Seq1', 'AAAAAAAAA'),
# ('>Name2.1_12-78_-__Seq2', '--AAAAAAA')]
#
# or
#
#[('>Name1.1_3HSPs_-__Sp1', 'AAAAAACCCCCCCCCCDDDDD'),
# ('>Name2.1_20-89_-__Sp2', 'AAAAAACCCCCCCCCCC----'),
#  ('>Name2.1_78-200_-__Sp2', '-------CCCCCCCCCCDDDD')]
```

Please note that I have checked for concatenation of only *consecutive* sequences from the text files, and that you would have to re-use the methods I've written in a different script for accounting for combinations. I leave that to your discretion.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @darthbhyrava. I updated the question with a more elaborate exemple at the end of the file with my real data. Maybe you will have an idea how to adapt your code to this example as well?

Comment: I have responded in the chat linked in the comments to your question, but I'll reply here as well. If you have to simply merge two names if there is no `__` in the name, then you could trigger a string addition instead of calling the `concat_name()` method. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as follows.

```
from collections import defaultdict
with open('lines.txt','r') as fp:
    lines=fp.readlines()

dnalist = defaultdict(list)
for i,line in enumerate(lines):
    line = line.replace('\n','')
    if i%2: #'Name' in line:
        dnalist[n].append(line)
    else:
        n = line.split('-')[-1]
```

That gives you a dictionary with keys being the file numbers and values being the dna sequences in a list.

```
def calc_ratio(str1,str2):
    n_skipped,n_matched,n_notmatched=0,0,0
    print(len(str1),len(str2))
    for i,ch in enumerate(str1):
        if ch=='-' or str2[i]=='-':
            n_skipped +1
        elif ch == str2[i]:
            n_matched += 1
        else:
            n_notmatched+=1
    retval = float(n_matched)/float(n_matched+n_notmatched+n_skipped)
    print(n_matched,n_notmatched,n_skipped)
    return retval
```

That gets you the ratio; you might want to consider the case where characters in the sequences dont match (and neither is '-'), here I assumed that's not a different case than one being '-'.

A helper function to concatenate the strings: here I took the case of non-matching chars and put in an 'X' to mark it (if it ever happens) .

```
def dna_concat(str1,str2):
    outstr=[]
    for i,ch in enumerate(str1):
        if ch!=str2[i]:
            if ch == '-':
                outchar = str2[i]
            elif str2[i] == '-':
                outchar = ch
            else:
                outchar = 'X'
        else:
            outchar = ch
        outstr.append(outchar)
    outstr = ''.join(outstr)
    return outstr
```

And finally a loop thru the dictionary lists to get the concatenated answers, in another dictionary with filenumbers as keys and lists of concatenations as values.

```
for filenum,dnalist in dnalist.items():
    print(dnalist)
    answers = defaultdict(list)
    for i,seq in enumerate(dnalist):
        for seq2 in dnalist[i+1:len(dnalist)]:
            ratio = calc_ratio(seq,seq2)
            print('i {} {} ration {}'.format(seq,seq2,ratio))
            if ratio<0.2:
                answers[filenum].append(dna_concat(seq,seq2))
                print(dna_concat(seq,seq2))
```

Comment: Hello @jeremy_rutman, thank you a lot for your help. I updated the question with a more elaborate exemple at the end of the file with my real data. Maybe you will have an idea how to adapt your code to this example as well?

Comment: I edited to use your real filenames, splitting on anything after the dash (so the two lines ending with Agapornis_vilveti get considered for concatenation.)